# if in the directory, files size is less than 2.1kb move the files to another directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to move file to another directory, if the files size is less than 2.1kb.
There are multiple files in the directory.
Please let me know how to resolve this.
I can not use mv command as there are large number of files in the directory, it has to be using find command.

Comment: Kindly do mention in your post whatever you have tried in your question and do let us know then.

Comment: Read [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) & [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) and learn how to combine both.

Comment: Try `find . -type f -size -2150c ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem with removing large number of files. You can use `find` for doing operations on large number of files.
It could be used in a way like this

```
find sourceDirectory -type f -exec mv {} destinationDirectory/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -size -2100c -type f -exec mv {} new_directory/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other answers are really close. This should do it for you:

`find /path/to/old_dir -size 2100c -type f -exec mv {} /path/to/new_dir/ \;`